# What do i need to add, so my JavaScript would work as i want it to?

Tags: javascript, browser, alert

I started learning **JavaScript**, and this is my first game i built:  Rock, Paper, Scissors.
*(Player vs Computer)* Now, everything is working, but i couldn't figure out how to make ***this***:

When result is tie, the game starts again asking if i would like to play again, without having to refresh the browser.

Please **don't answer with jQuery**, I'm trying to learn JavaScript! :)

Here is my snippet:

```js
// declare variables
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

// prevent the user from choosing a different answer
if (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors") {
  userChoice = prompt("Your answer is not acceptable! Please choose again!");
}

// pick a random answer from computer
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
alert("Computer: " + computerChoice);

// check who wins
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    alert("The result is a tie!");
  } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      alert("rock wins");
    } else {
      alert("paper wins");
    }
  } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      alert("paper wins");
    } else {
      alert("scissors win");
    }
  }
}

// call the function
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're basically looking to do is wrap the game in a larger contextual loop, which itself just checks for a terminating condition to the game.

Structurally, let's assume the entirety of your game is enclosed in a function:

```
function playGame() {
    // all the code you have now
}
```

Then the loop would have a structure like this:

```
while (true) {
    playGame();

    if (!confirm("Would you like to play again?")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can of course get fancier with the confirmation, or perhaps use a value to control the loop rather than an infinite loop with a `break`.  But the concept is the same.  The overall loop will continue to repeat and "play again" until some condition exists which would cause it to stop.

So in your case, you want to check if it's a tie, yes?  Structurally something like this:

```
while (true) {
    playGame();

    if (!gameIsTie()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

or:

```
var winner = 0;

while (winner == 0) {
    playGame();
    winner = determineWinner();
}
```

Wherein you would implement the functions needed to determine if the game is a tie, or if there is a winner, etc.

Comment: I've never heard "game loop" in the context of a turn-based/wait-for-user-input-before-doing-anything-at-all game. Usually it applies to the control loop in a video game with animated graphics, where the loop continually checks/updates the state and then repaints the screen.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Maybe my terminology is wrong?  Certainly possible, I don't really do any game programming.  Is there a name for this kind of loop then?  I'd hate to keep using it incorrectly.

Comment: @David thanks for answering, i understand it now. :D

Comment: Well, it *is* literally a loop controlling the game, and maybe the term is used this way too. (That's why I said "I've never heard..." and not "That's an incorrect use of...".) Either way the code you've shown is a good solution to this problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn: A casual Google search seems to lean much more heavily toward your use, so I went ahead and changed the wording in the answer to hopefully avoid confusion from future visitors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put all in function and call if is tie.

```js
(function game(){
// declare variables
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

// prevent the user from choosing a different answer
if (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors") {
  userChoice = prompt("Your answer is not acceptable! Please choose again!");
}

// pick a random answer from computer
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
alert("Computer: " + computerChoice);

// check who wins
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    alert("The result is a tie!");
    var newGame = prompt("Play again?");
    if(newGame === 'yes'){
      game();
    }
  } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      alert("rock wins");
    } else {
      alert("paper wins");
    }
  } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      alert("paper wins");
    } else {
      alert("scissors win");
    }
  }
}

// call the function
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
})()
```

Comment: But if you had a spectacularly long run of ties you'd get a stack overflow, wouldn't you?

Comment: How much games you need for stack overflow? 
If you are worry for this, first must worry for use prompt instead of better way.